# Editing SWF files using Transform SWF for Java from Flagstone

Tags: java, flash

Has anyone successfully used the Transform SWF for Java library from  [Flagstone Software][1]

[1]: http://www.flagstonesoftware.com/transform/index.html to edit an existing swf file. Mainly what I want to accomplish is load a swf file and replace images or texts dynamically. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is a little bit late, but google searchers will still land here :-) This code will color the first text span of all text elements to red.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.zip.DataFormatException;

import com.flagstone.transform.Movie;
import com.flagstone.transform.MovieTag;
import com.flagstone.transform.datatype.Color;
import com.flagstone.transform.text.DefineText;

public class Flash {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws MalformedURLException, DataFormatException, IOException {
        Movie m = new Movie();
        m.decodeFromFile(new File("C:\\tmp\\Movie.swf"));

        for (MovieTag mt : m.getObjects()) {
            System.out.println(mt.getClass() + "  " + mt.toString());
            if (mt instanceof DefineText) {
                ((DefineText) mt).getSpans().get(0).setColor(new Color(255, 0, 0));
            }
        }

        m.encodeToFile(new File("C:\\tmp\\foo.swf"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I am working on a desktop application that generates swf files. It is a little tricky but the samples in the Cookbook will help you a lot. Just go through the samples and you will find almost anything that you need.One thing is that, the developer stopped working on the framwork but it still works fine. Transform library only supports Flash 10 and Translate supports ActionScript 1.0. I had to change the ActionScript 2 and 3 code to AS1 for the framework to work which was for me to only replace the variable types when declaring variables.